# Can’t enable encryption in YugabyteDB cluster using yugabyted cli

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm running the yb-cluster of 3 logical node on 1 VM. I am trying with SSL Mode enabled cluster. Below is the property file i am using to start the cluster with SSL Mode ON:

```
./bin/yugabyted start --config /data/ybd1/config_1.config
 ./bin/yugabyted start                   --base_dir=/data/ybd2                   --listen=127.0.0.2                   --join=192.168.56.12
 ./bin/yugabyted start                   --base_dir=/data/ybd3                   --listen=127.0.0.3                   --join=192.168.56.12
```

my config file:

```
{
"base_dir": "/data/ybd1",
"listen": "192.168.56.12",
"certs_dir": "/root/192.168.56.12/",
"allow_insecure_connections": "false",
"use_node_to_node_encryption": "true"
"use_client_to_server_encryption": "true"
}
```

I am able to connect using:

```
 bin/ysqlsh -h 127.0.0.3  -U yugabyte -d yugabyte
ysqlsh (11.2-YB-2.11.1.0-b0)
Type "help" for help.
yugabyte=# \l
                                   List of databases
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------------+----------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres        | postgres | UTF8     | C       | en_US.UTF-8 |
 system_platform | postgres | UTF8     | C       | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0       | postgres | UTF8     | C       | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |         |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres | UTF8     | C       | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |         |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 yugabyte        | postgres | UTF8     | C       | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

But when I am trying to connect to my yb-cluster from psql client. I am getting below errors.

```
 psql -h 192.168.56.12 -p 5433
psql: error: connection to server at "192.168.56.12", port 5433 failed: FATAL:  Timed out: OpenTable RPC (request call id 2) to 192.168.56.12:9100 timed out after 120.000s
postgres@acff2570dfbc:~$
```

And in yb t-server logs I am getting below errors:

```
I0228 05:00:21.248733 21631 async_initializer.cc:90] Successfully built ybclient
2022-02-28 05:02:21.248 UTC [21624] FATAL:  Timed out: OpenTable RPC (request call id 2) to 192.168.56.12:9100 timed out after 120.000s
I0228 05:02:21.251086 21627 poller.cc:66] Poll stopped: Service unavailable (yb/rpc/scheduler.cc:80): Scheduler is shutting down (system error 108)
2022-02-28 05:54:20.987 UTC [23729] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

Any HELP in this regard is really apricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re setting your config wrong when using `yugabyted` tool. You want to use `--master_flags` and `--tserver_flags` like explained in the docs: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yugabyted/#flags.
An example:

```
bin/yugabyted start --base_dir=/data/ybd1 --listen=192.168.56.12 --tserver_flags=use_client_to_server_encryption=true,ysql_enable_auth=true,use_cassandra_authentication=true,certs_for_client_dir=/root/192.168.56.12/
```

Sending the parameters this way should work on your cluster.